# Como fazer para que div´s colapsáveis abram sem que os botões das outras div´s desçam?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Eu estou a fazer uma galeria de portfólio, baseada em Bootstrap de maneira a que fique responsiva. 
Por isso tenho um conjunto de miniaturas que vão corresponder a um trabalho que deverão estar alinhadas:
[image: miniaturas]

Ao clicarmos nelas abrem uma DIV colapsível.
Eu pretendo que quando essa `div` se abra, as outras miniaturas da mesma linha continuem no lugar:

[image: disposição correcta]

E que não desçam quando clicamos numa delas:

[image: disposição incorrecta]

Mas isto de maneira a que a que a ordem das tag´s HTML não seja alterada para que seja possível que em pequenos dispositivos a disposição seja assim:

[image: mobile]

Gostaria também de saber se existe alguma opção que faça com que não seja apenas possível a abertura de uma `div` colapsível de cada vez.

O meu código é este:
[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/GJLHx/2/)

Comment: Uma pergunta, quando uma estiver aberta e você clicar em outra, você vai fazer o efeito de fechar e abrir ou apenas vai trocar o conteúdo que está no meio?

Comment: @Erlon Charles Gostaria do efeito de fechar e abrir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui fica uma sugestão:

```
var bigMedia = $(window).width() < 750 ? false : true;  // detectar se o ecrã é grande ou pequeno
$(window).resize(function () {
    bigMedia = $(window).width() < 750 ? false : true; // no caso de um resize do ecrã, detectar novamente
});
var conteudo;
$('.panel-heading').on('click', function () {
    conteudo && conteudo.slideToggle(function () { // se houver um conteudo aberto, fechá-lo
        $(this).remove();  // e removê-lo depois de fechado
    });    

    if (!bigMedia) $(this).parent().next().slideToggle('collapse'); // se for ecrã pequeno abrir como o HTML está
    else { // se for ecrã grande: 
        conteudo = $(this).parent().next().clone(); // fazer um clone do conteudo
        conteudo.attr('id', ''); // remover ID para não duplicar
        $(this).closest('.container').append(conteudo); // adicionár o clone ao fim de cada ".container"
        conteudo.slideToggle();  // abrir
    }
});
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/2vbja/)

**Note que** eu retirei todo o seu Javascript e escreví novo código.

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54220/discussion-on-answer-by-sergio-como-fazer-para-que-divs-colapsaveis-abram-sem-q)